# ListView Columns inside ListView Row, or QML's handling of list of lists

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qtquick2

I have an XML response that contains a list of items. Each item contains another list of sub-items. I'm able to successfully translate that into models in QML, but I'm having problems with dislaying list of lists.

I want to render list of items as `Row`s, each having their title; and the list of sub-items horizontally appended as `Column`s to their corresponding `Row`. It seems like this should be easy from the QML documentation of each of those components using `ListView`, but I'm running into 2 problems:

- the sub-items `Column` is overlayed on the "title" `Column` of the `Row`
- only the first sub-item is displayed, the rest are ignored

Here's the relatively minimal QML (which can be run with `qmlscene`) to reproduce:

```
import QtQuick 2.5

ListView {
    width: 640
    height: 480

    model: ListModel {
        ListElement { title: "title 1" }
        ListElement { title: "title 2" }
    }

    delegate: Row {
        width: parent.width
        Text {
            text: title
            elide: Text.ElideRight
        }
        ListView {
            orientation: ListView.Horizontal
            model: ListModel {
                ListElement { name: "name 1"; description: "desc 1" }
                ListElement { name: "name 2"; description: "desc 2" }
            }
            delegate: Column {
                Text { text: "name: " + name + "; desc: " + description }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The expected output is:

```
title 1 name: name 1; desc: desc1 name: name 2; desc: desc 2
title 2 name: name 1; desc: desc1 name: name 2; desc: desc 2
```

Am I using the `ListView` in a wrong place? Or are there other components I should be using to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't mean to use nested vertical listviews? That would be sub-optimal usability-wise.

```
import QtQuick 2.5

ListView {
    width: 640
    height: 480

    model: ListModel {
        ListElement { title: "title 1" }
        ListElement { title: "title 2" }
    }

    delegate: Row {
        width: parent.width
        Text {
            text: title
            width: 100
            elide: Text.ElideRight
        }
        Column {
            Repeater {
                model: ListModel {
                    ListElement { name: "name 1"; description: "desc 1" }
                    ListElement { name: "name 2"; description: "desc 2" }
                }
                delegate: Column {
                    Text { text: "name: " + name + "; desc: " + description }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works visually (after I remove the outer `Column` - since I want sub-items appended horizontally to the row). But, AFAICT, the difference is that with the `ListView`, if the content is too wide, it can be scrolled since it implements `Flickable`, but with the `Repeater` it would just disappear off screen. And yes, I got the idea of using nested `ListView`s from this post - http://www.mail-archive.com/qt-qml@trolltech.com/msg00808.html . So is this a bug? Should it also work with `ListView` (or `GridView`)?

Comment: So did you mean to make the nested ListView horizontal? The very least, you should give it a size. The same thing for the lonely Text element inside the neighbour column. By default it will just expand to anything that is needed to fit the text (implicit size).

Comment: Adding the explicit size(s) and orientation, unfortunately, doesn't change the behavior. The list is still starting at the left-most position of the `Row`, overlaid on top of the "title" column, and still, only the first item is displayed.

Comment: Could you provide the updated code, and possibly some mockup or something that illustrates how you would like it to look?

Comment: Sure, I updated the code and added expected output in question body. Thank you for your help so far.